# how to undo edits someone else did on my own posts?

Tags: support, edits, review-lists, review-queues

someone edited my question as you can see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75284)
and on the picture below.

[this is the question in the discussion here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145628/user-login-name-on-process-unknown/145670#145670).

[image]

the edit was approved (obviously it was a mistake)

how can I undo this edit on my answer??

what the user added to my answer should have been a comment.

in my opinion he should not have access to edit my answer. I would consider this a bug.

Comment: Rolled back the edit for you. Will let a mod answer your questions though

Comment: Agree that this edit shouldn't have been approved. Disagree that this is a bug, though.

Comment: @AndriyM so you think that a user just arrive to the site, with no reputation and already has the right to edit someone's answer? I don't even think he knew what he was doing. That should have been a comment.

Comment: We cannot possibly know if they didn't know what they were doing or if they were actually an experienced SE user. In any event, the system doesn't apply such edits immediately. The mistake was on the approver, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh I understand what you are saying.

Comment: would it be a valid suggestion perhaps to set a minimum reputation before you can edit answers that not your own?? just food for thoughts, because I don't even know if that would be something possible and easy to implement.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli Any suggestion is valid, but my personal opinion is that the review requirement for suggested edits usually works fine. Things can slip through every now and then but that is why you get the option to rollback if you disagree with the approved edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you check what's directly under the bottom of your post, there are two links like [edited 2 hours ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/145670/revisions) and the 'card' of the editor.  If you click the former, you will get to the revision history of that post.  You'll see something like in this picture:

[image: revision history excerpt]

On every state, except the newest one, there is a 'rollback' link.  If you click it, the question will be set to that given state.  The changes that are rolled back this way are still visible in the history.

Answer (score 4):

Besides dezso's answer, which covers how you can see the history of the edits of a question and how to rollback, there is one more point:

> In my opinion he should not have access to edit my answer. I would consider this a bug.

No, it is not a bug. A central point of the whole idea behind Stack Oveflow and the sister sites is that anyone can post questions and answers and anyone can edit both. So:

There are also certain provisions to prevent undesired behaviours like deleting or vandalizing posts, war edits, etc. For example, unregistered users or users with low reputation can only suggest edits and cannot directly make any edit. Only then the OP or other high rep users can accept or reject the edit.

And even if a mistake happens, anyone (with enough rep) can also roll back the unwanted/mistaken edit. And, finally:

> How can I undo this edit on my answer?

**Yes**, you can go and roll back the unwanted edit. But

**No**, it's not your answer any more. You are just the original poster, anyone can edit and improve your answer. You will still get a notification for a change in any of your questions or answers, so you can review and roll back if necessary.