# Undo accepted edit back to pending, not full revert

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible but thought I would ask and maybe possibly consider potentially requesting.

Similar to [how to undo edits someone else did on my own posts?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/how-to-undo-edits-someone-else-did-on-my-own-posts), I just had an edit of one of my answers approved: [Suggested Edit for "How do I check that the database master key encryption is valid?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94008). I believe the approval was premature as it might be incorrect information. Someone was nice enough to post a comment mentioning the pending edit and their reason for caution on approving. I appreciated that communication as I plan on testing the suggestion to prove it correct or incorrect. I don't mind approving if correct, but I certainly don't want incorrect information being out there. Sure, the reviewers who accepted should have been more cautious, but that's not very helpful since the edit has been approved and is publicly visible.

Ideally, I would simply change the state of the edit back to "pending" so that I have time to verify. Then I can either reject, improve, or approve. But as it stands, it feels a little messy to revert if the edit is somehow correct, as I would then need to re-apply the update or do another revert, both of which just seem like more junk data cluttering things up, convoluting the history. Maybe nobody cares about that, so perhaps a non-issue. And maybe it is far more complicated than it is worth ( [Change edit approval/rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88096/change-edit-approval-rejection) ) but at the very least it seems like it would be nice to have some clear guidance on the preferred approach to this situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rolling back the edit would seem to me a perfectly fair course of action in this situation. You are not required/expected to be able to immediately validate someone's update which was approved without your participation. And if you aren't sure about it, you don't have to accept it – particularly if neither the suggester nor any of the approvers left a comment to justify the edit in any way. (I realise the person who suggested this specific edit simply couldn't leave a comment, but either of the approvers could.)

You can always roll back to the newer revision once you've got time to verify the suggestion. No need to worry about cluttering up history – that's not what this site is about, after all. Valid information in the most up-to-date revision of the post is what really counts.

Comment: Thanks. I have reverted the edit. I will review the proposed change when I get a chance, and if it happens to be correct, then I will put it back (well, after cleaning it up a little ;-).